# Pendant Cutting dimension

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

[image]

Was wondering if you can help me with a calculation.  I have a somewhat (not exact) square or rectangular piece of cloth.  I want to cut three pendants out of the cloth.  For mounting, at the wide end of the pendent, I cut it square to facilitate mounting, so the wide end of the pendent is wider than A.

I can accurately measure the width (2 * A) and length (L) of the cloth.  I accurately know (B).

How do I calculate C?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that if you extend the lines that intersect the $L$ edge you get isosceles triangles. Lets call the horizontal part of this $X$. Then you have similar triangles, where you can write $$\frac{X}{B}=\frac{X+C}{L}$$
You also have that $$X+C=\frac{A+X}{2}$$
These form a system with two linear equations with two unknowns, $X$ and $C$, which should be easy to solve.

Comment: Thank you for your help!